# Why is BufferedInputStream.read() returning -1 in Android Nougat when it use to return 0?

Tags: android

When testing my application on an Android N device I discovered that I had many new issues related to the way I use BufferedInputStream. The issue seems to be how I interpret the return value from BufferedInputStream.read(). If 0 was returned I assumed 0 bytes were available to be read from the underlying stream, if -1 I assumed the underlying stream had reached the end of the file (and exited reading). This worked fine until Nougat. Now when the underlying InputStream.read() returns 0, BufferedInputStream.read() returns -1. What’s the correct behavior? Why has this changed?

Here is a distilled example ...

```
   class ZeroBytesReadInputStream extends InputStream {
        ...
        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buffer, int byteOffset, int byteCount) throws IOException {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private int testZeroBytesReadBufferedInputStream() {
        InputStream inputStream = new ZeroBytesReadInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        int valueReturned = 0;
        try {
            byte[] toStream = new byte[100];
            valueReturned = bufferedInputStream.read(toStream, 0, 100);
            Log.d("Zero Bytes Read Test", "BufferedInputStream returned = " + valueReturned + ". Android Version = " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return valueReturned;
    }
```

Output when run -
`10-19 09:28:51.970  9138  9138 D Zero Bytes Read Test: BufferedInputStream returned = -1. Android Version = 24`

`10-19 09:32:19.200 12675 12675 D Zero Bytes Read Test: BufferedInputStream returned = 0. Android Version = 23`

Comment: Please do not say that BufferedInputStream returns something. Its the read() function that returns a value.

Comment: 'return 0;'. Your let your read function always return 0. Blame yourself. And it reads nothing.

Comment: @greenapps Read the question - that is on purpose to test the behavior of `BufferedInputStream` when the underlying stream returns 0!

Comment: I am @greg-nield's coworker. He was maintaining my code. Just a reminder that it is never smart to have a non-standard implementation (of InputStream in my case) no matter good you think your reasons are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)), the method should actually never return 0 unless the `len` argument was 0:

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is
>   detected, or an exception is thrown.
>
> If len is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise,
>   there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available
>   because the stream is at end of file, the value -1 is returned;
>   otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.

Therefore, the unterlying stream implementation is buggy, and thus the behavior of `BufferedInputStream` is indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks. This was a great answer. I'll have to review how my InputStream is implemented in the app.

Comment: @GregNield Thank you for the feedback! Happy coding :)